# binding matrices with different dimension lengths

Tags: arrays, r, multidimensional-array

i'm trying to create a 3d array built of many matrices binded together.

I use the following code:

```
completeMatrix = matrix(c(1:20), nrow=10, ncol=2)
for (i in 1:3) {
  newMatrix <- matrix(c(1:20), nrow=10, ncol=2)
  completeMatrix <- abind(completeMatrix, newMatrix , along = 3)
}
newMatrix <- matrix(c(1:18), nrow=9, ncol=2)
completeMatrix <- abind(completeMatrix, newMatrix, along = 3)
```

I have a problem adding the newest "newMatrix" to the 3d array since it has different number of rows.

Thanks

Comment: Not clear about the expected output especially when you are creating the same object names a couple of times.

Comment: I'm using the same object name for simplicity. You can imagine each run of the for loops creates a different matrix, and binds it to one large 3d matrix. There's an issue when the small matrices include different number of rows which i would like to overcome.

Comment: It may be better to show the expected output so that it becomes a bit more clear.

Comment: You should give the viewer the option of filling the "missing" rows with NA's and you should do some searching on SO since I seem to remember this question being asked before, at least for matrices.